# iOS Launch Screen Storyboard vs Launch Images

Tags: ios, startup, launch-screen

So, we have two options:

1. Launch Screen Storyboard
2. Launch Images

I found out that 'Launch Screen Storyboard' option is the easiest and most efficient, but if you want rounded edges or borders on certain elements, you are constrained.

'Launch Images' gives you way more room for you to create static PNG's of your UI.  However, they create more files and add to app size.

Apple Indicates: ([here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/))

> It’s best to use an Xcode storyboard for your launch screen, but you can provide a set of static images if necessary.

During run time, in real life, which is faster? Which makes app launch faster or easier on the system?

Comment: Neither is faster. iOS actually generates an image from the launch screen storyboard and uses that when the app is launched.

Answer (score 1):

[App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

It depends on the amount of artwork you are displaying in the launch screen vs the image size in the launch image. Also techniques like app thinning will create the right variant for each device type to pick the right asset avoiding other which are not necessary.

Check out this link when you are using image assets

Answer (score 1):

iOS is fast enough to load either storyboard or image. There's no need to worry at all, just do what's the most handy for you.

By the way, there's a third option:
Let iOS first show the static launch screen/image. Then show your first view controller having the exact same layout as your launch image but adding dynamic UI elements. This first view controller should be alpha animated in. Examples of added dynamic UI elements: loading progress bar, or Sign Up / Log In buttons.